# DynamoDB, how to get negetion from begin_with() like !begin_with()

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I want to check that my expression does not begin with some prefix

```
"condition" : {
    "expression": "!begins_with($index, :prefix)",
    "expressionValues" : {
      ":prefix": $utils.dynamodb.toStringJson($prefix)
    }
  }
```

In which way i can do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by

> NOT

```
"expression": "NOT begins_with($index, :prefix)"
```